# network graph using igraph() from lm() regression output

Tags: r

I'd like to get a visual overview of the output of a linear regression model.

I'd like to be build a network plot with unidirectional edges using the output from a regression model, and I'd like to only include predictors with a **p-value <0.05** (so to end up with a structure like the one I've plotted manually below).

Ideally, I'd also like the edges to be **green** when there is a positive association, **red** when there is a negative association, and to be **thicker** when there is a strong association.

It's my first time working with network/network-like graphs, and I'm at loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# PACKAGES 
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(igraph)

# DATA 
mtcars

# MODEL AND OUTPUT 
mymodel = mtcars %>% do(myfit = lm(mpg ~  wt + gear +carb, data = .))
mymodCoef = tidy(mymodel, myfit)
mymodCoef <- as.data.frame(mymodCoef)

# WHAT I'D LIKE TO PLOT TO LOOK LIKE 
plot(graph_from_literal(wt--+mpg, carb--+mpg))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a data frame representing an edge list in the format of:

- column1 = node where the edge is coming from
- column2 = node where the edge is going to
- columnn... = attributes you want to store in the edge

Then you will need to input that df into `graph_from_data_frame`

Two of the attributes you can store in the edge list are **color** and **width** which will automatically be plotted in **igraph**'s base `plot` function.

```
edge_list <- mymodCoef %>%
  mutate(source = term,
         target = 'mpg',
         color = sapply(statistic, function(x){ifelse(x<0, 'red', 'green')}),
         width = abs(statistic)/(max(abs(statistic))) * 10) %>%
  filter(p.value <= .05) %>%
  select(source, target, color, statistic, width)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edge_list, directed = F)

plot(g)
```

If you wanted to explicitly plot the color and width, then

```
plot(g, edge.width = E(g)$width, edge.color = E(g)$color)
```

Sometimes you'll need to play around with scales - for instance, the difference in *statistic* scores are at most 2 and will look identical if you used the raw *statistic* score as the line width. If you want to get scaling for free, then you can use **ggraph**:

```
library(ggraph)
ggraph(g) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_colour = color,
                     edge_width = abs(statistic))) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = c('green' = 'green', 'red' = 'red'))
```

If you want to learn more about plotting with igraph, then some of the best tutorials for plotting in igraph can be found in Katherine Ognyanova's website: http://kateto.net/netscix2016